# Latest updated categories list query, exclude one from displaying

Tags: categories, link-category

I have this query:

```
$cat_array = array();
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'exclude' => '187',
      'posts_per_page' => 19,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $cat_args=array('orderby' => 'none');
        $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'category', $cat_args);
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
          $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
        }
      endwhile;
    }
    if ($cat_array) {
      foreach($cat_array as $cat) {
        $category = get_term_by('ID',$cat, 'category');
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($category, 'category')) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View latest posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>'.'</li>';
      }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
```

Which is listing the latest updated categories. All good. But I want to exclude a particular category from listing over there. That can be done like I have in the query`'exclude' => '187',`
 BUT the problem is with the following example:
 I have a post which belongs to two categories, one category is the one I don't want to display, and the other one is a category I do want to display. 
If I simply exclude it like I said above, none of the categories will display in the list, because it will completely exclude that post.
 How can I still show the other category, and hide the one I don't want tho show?

Any clue?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this with

```
 if ($cat_array) {
      foreach($cat_array as $cat) {
        $category = get_term_by('ID',$cat, 'category');
     if($category->name != 'Excluded category'){
        echo '<div class="catspace"><a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($category, 'category')) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "latest posts %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>'.'</div>';
     }else{echo '<div class="catspace">'. ''   .'</div>';    }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the excluded category in your `foreach`:

```
foreach ( $cat_array as $cat ) {
    if ( $cat != EXCLUDED_CAT_ID ) {
        // Output
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't get to try because I've already solved